# Dual boot installation has no effect (no GRUB), Boot-Repair doesn't help

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

With a fresh Windows 10 machine (Lenovo H50-55) I did a dual-boot install with Fedora 23.  The installation seemed to go fine, but when I rebooted it went straight to Windows as if there was no [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB).  When I used [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) it found both Windows and Fedora on the machine, and its "repair" option chugged away, but it didn't fix the problem after a reboot; in fact, in comparing the Boot Info files from before and after the repair attempt it seems there wasn't really any changes.

**EDIT**: I also encountered the same problem after upgrading my machine's BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed [these instructions from It's F.O.S.S.](http://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) to use [bcdedit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx) in an admin-priveledged command prompt, but with a slightly different path since it was Fedora instead of Ubuntu:

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi

When I next rebooted I got to GRUB, which allowed me to boot into either Fedora or Windows.

**EDIT**: The same solution also worked after GRUB was ignored after upgrading my machine's BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Some new laptop has new features which is secure boot. Disable it from bios and boot the system.  More information can be find at 
https://blog.malwarebytes.org/security-world/2014/05/uefi-secureboot-and-dual-booting-windows-8-and-linux/

Comment: I'd tried disabling secure boot, it didn't help.